# Colonists on Mars who hunt each other, one operates an old spaceship and gets back to Earth

Tags: story-identification

I read this novel maybe in 1990, I think it was a few years older than that, I got it from a (now closed) UK library.

Some teen in a struggling colony on Mars is going to come of age, this involves going out at night, way beyond the village perimeter, and killing an enemy monster.
Sometimes nobody returns.

He goes out and wanders the desert and one of the creatures approaches him, it blurts out some words in English as, I think, he spears it. He has a close look and realises it's human with like breathing gear on.

On his return he is met by a party of village men and sworn to secrecy, he also realises they were ready to kill him, if he was badly wounded, so he wouldn't blurt stuff out in the medical room.

He creeps out one night (I think but am unsure) to investigate and gets captured by the enemy,  at their base it's revealed they are also a colony but more scientifically advanced, they have a spaceship but they can't access it, for some reason they need a person with his tribes DNA to open the control cabin.

After days of trying he finally gets in, but manages to seal the door before his captors can follow. He then interacts somehow with the craft and it flies him to Earth.

On Earth it is now a utopian society, while he is talking with them his spaceship is rapidly broken down and all the minerals etc are taken away.

He is then fitted with a neuro helmet and, in a few minutes, he gets a university degree education so he can understand the technology.

That's as much as I remember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is [The Iron Thorn](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?684809) by Algis Budrys, it matches your description almost perfectly.

Comment: Could you explain how this matches almost perfectly?

Comment: Yes, I managed to find my copy and this is definitely the correct book. Well identified :-)

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I saw 'Iron Thorn' it came back into my mind ....I gotta get me a copy now to see how it ended, I still don't recall that bit.